# How to check data type of a python object (int, float, str etc) in pybind 11module

Tags: c++, pybind11

I have a pybind module like

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(testmodule, m)
{
    // Assume Value class has been exposed here

    m.def("processDict", [](py::str expr, py::dict valueDict) {
        std::map<std::string, Value> cppValueDict;
        for (auto item : d) {
            // Convert key to std::string
            std::string key = item.first.cast<std::string>();
            
            // Trying to check python value type and cast it to custom datum type
            if (pybind11::isinstance(item.second, pybind11::int_) {
                cppValueDict.insert({key, CustomDatum::createIntDatum(pybind11::cast<int>(item.second))});
            } else {
                cppValueDict.insert({key, CustomDatum::createStringDatum(pybind11::cast<std::string>(item.second))});
            }
        }
        process(expr, cppValueDict);
   });
}
```

Unfortunately, if I try calling this from a python script with a dict like `dict_obj = {"a": 1, "b": "Hello"}`, it throws an error saying "Unable to cast Python instance of type <class 'int'> to C++ type 'std::string'", which indicates to me that it returns false in the if condition block.

What is the proper way of type checking in pybind11 for python types (primitive or custom)?

Comment: Just a wild guess, and I don't have time to check it, but try the templated version of `isinstance` instead -- `py::isinstance<py::int_>(item.second)`.

Comment: @DanMašek that works. If you want to put in as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but now I'm curious how it ever throws anything, it shouldn't even compile. First of all there's a missing closing `)` in the `if (pybind11::isinstance(item.second, pybind11::int_)`. and furthermore, `pybind11::int_` is a type, not a value, and you're trying to pass is as an argument to a function. At least my compiler frowns upon that.

Comment: Just a hint for the future: try to make your [mcve] more complete. Other than the actual problem, nothing else should have to be added, or removed by the person answering your question. Note how the example I provided in the answer is different from yours -- something along those lines ought to be what you include in your question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two overloads of `pybind11::isinstance`:

1. [`template<typename T, detail::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<object, T>::value, int> = 0> bool isinstance(handle obj`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv4I0_N6detail11enable_if_tINSt10is_base_ofI6object1TE5valueEiEEE10isinstanceb6handle)
2. [`inline bool isinstance(handle obj, handle type)`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv410isinstance6handle6handle)

The problem is that you're using the latter, but you're passing a type (`pybind11::int_`) as the second parameter, rather than a value (a `pybind11::handle` or `pybind11::object` instance holding a Python type object). That's not valid in C++ AFAIK, so I don't know how that even compiled on your end.

In order for this to work, you'd have to fetch the `int` type object from the interpreter, and use that. Something like the following, for example:

```
auto python_int_type = py::globals()["__builtins__"].attr("int");
if (py::isinstance(item.second, python_int_type)) {
    // ...
}
```

A better approach seems to be to use the first, templated overload:

```
if (py::isinstance<py::int_>(item.second)) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;


PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(testmodule, m)
{
    m.def("processDict", [](py::str expr, py::dict valueDict) {
        for (auto item : valueDict) {
            // Convert key to std::string
            std::string key = item.first.cast<std::string>();
            std::cout << "The key is '" << key << "' and the value ";

            // Trying to check python value type and cast it to custom datum type
            if (py::isinstance<py::int_>(item.second)) {
                auto value = py::cast<int>(item.second);
                std::cout << "is an INT: " << value << "\n";
            } else {
                auto value = py::cast<std::string>(item.second);
                std::cout << "is a STRING: " << value << "\n";
            }
        }
    });
}

int main()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    try {
        py::exec(R"(
            import testmodule
            testmodule.processDict("test", {"a":1, "b":"two"})
        )");
    } catch (py::error_already_set& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
The key is 'a' and the value is an INT: 1
The key is 'b' and the value is a STRING: two
```

---

Note: It might be a good idea to also add another check for the `string` type, rather than assuming that if it's not an int, it's got to be a string. And throw a meaningful error when it's not any of supported types. I'll leave that as an excercise for the reader.